# Unable to connect to database when oracle driver is added to Maven repository

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jdbc, ojdbc

I am trying to write a simple webservice which reads/writes info to a database. I figure the oracle driver `ojdbc6` cannot be added as a dependency in pom.xml, so I added it using the below mvn install command.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\ojdbc6.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

`ojdbc6.jar` got added successfully
[`ojdbc6.jar`][1]

My DAO class trying to retrieve product info from database:

```
    package com.nt.dao;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.classic.Session;

import com.nt.dto.ProductDTO;

public class ProductServiceDAO {

    public ProductDTO getProductInfo(long productId) {
        System.out.println("session---------1-");
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        System.out.println("session---------2-");
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        ProductDTO productDTO = new ProductDTO();
        productDTO.setProductName("Apple");
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        System.out.println("session---------3-");
        productDTO = (ProductDTO) session.get(ProductDTO.class, productId);
        session.close();
        return productDTO;
    }
}
```

When I try to run the program, I received below exception. Please help.

```
 Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection

at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:99)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
at com.nt.dao.ProductServiceDAO.getProductInfo(ProductServiceDAO.java:17)
at com.nt.bo.ProductServiceBO.getProductInfo(ProductServiceBO.java:10)
at com.nt.ws.impl.ProductServiceImpl.getProductInfo(ProductServiceImpl.java:12)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:181)
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:97)
... 40 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:133)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
... 53 more
```

Comment: The ojdbc6.jar is added to maven local repository now. Still the issue.

Comment: Can you show your pom? And where you configure your datasource?

Comment: If it's in your pom.xml, check the run time package.  Maybe the JAR isn't available in the CLASSPATH.  Your URL looks right to me.

Comment: you sure you cannot add it in your pom.xml? `<dependency>
    <groupId>oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
`

Comment: can you also show your hibernate configuration?

Comment: jdk u're using ?

Comment: It seemed to be that the driver is not on the classpath while starting the application?

Comment: It's working now. I added the below line of code in my class

Comment: It's working now. I added 'Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");' to my code. But I am facing another problem here, please see my post. @pirho

Comment: It's working now. I added 'Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");' to my code. But I am facing another problem here, please see my post. @duffymo

Comment: Yes, added  @sfat

Answer (score 0):

It's working now. I added the below line of code in my class

```
Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
```

But I am facing another problem here. My "products" table has a record as shown in below screenshot.[products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85OzN.png)

When I try to retrieve the record in SOAPUI, it is not retrieved. Moreover, the record is deleted. Below is SOAPUI screenshot

[soap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yprWa.png)

My ProducDTO class:

```
    package com.nt.dto;

    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

    @XmlType(name="ProductDTO")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class ProductDTO {
        @XmlElement
        private int productId;
        @XmlElement
        private String productName;
        @XmlElement
        private int productPrice;
        public int getProductId() {
            return productId;
        }
        public void setProductId(int productId) {
            this.productId = productId;
        }
        public String getProductName() {
            return productName;
        }
        public void setProductName(String productName) {
            this.productName = productName;
        }
        public int getProductPrice() {
            return productPrice;
        }
        public void setProductPrice(int productPrice) {
            this.productPrice = productPrice;
        }


    }

My DAO class retrieving the record:

package com.nt.dao;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.classic.Session;

import com.nt.dto.ProductDTO;

public class ProductServiceDAO {

    public ProductDTO getProductInfo(long productId) {
        System.out.println("session---------1-");
        try {
            Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        System.out.println("session---------2-");
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        ProductDTO productDTO = new ProductDTO();

        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        System.out.println("session---------3-"+productId);
        productDTO = (ProductDTO) session.get(ProductDTO.class, (int) productId);
        if(productDTO!=null){
            System.out.println("session---------4-"+productDTO.getProductId());
            System.out.println("session---------5-"+productDTO.getProductName());
            System.out.println("session---------6-"+productDTO.getProductPrice());
        }else{
            System.out.println("session---------7-");
        }

        session.close();
        return productDTO;
    }
}
```

My log file:

```
    Payload: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.nt.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:getProductInfo>
         <productId>159</productId>
      </ws:getProductInfo>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
--------------------------------------
session---------1-
session---------2-
session---------3-159
Hibernate: 
    /* load com.nt.dto.ProductDTO */ select
        productdto0_.PRODUCT_ID as PRODUCT1_5_0_,
        productdto0_.PRODUCT_NAME as PRODUCT2_5_0_,
        productdto0_.PRODUCT_PRICE as PRODUCT3_5_0_ 
    from
        PRODUCTS productdto0_ 
    where
        productdto0_.PRODUCT_ID=?
session---------7-
Nov 19, 2017 7:58:18 PM org.apache.cxf.services.ProductServiceService.ProductServicePort.ProductService
INFO: Outbound Message
---------------------------
ID: 2
Response-Code: 200
Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: text/xml
Headers: {}
Payload: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><ns2:getProductInfoResponse xmlns:ns2="http://ws.nt.com/"/></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
--------------------------------------
```

My DAO class:

```
package com.nt.dao;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.classic.Session;

import com.nt.dto.ProductDTO;

public class ProductServiceDAO {

    public ProductDTO getProductInfo(long productId) {
        System.out.println("session---------1-");
        try {
            Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        System.out.println("session---------2-");
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        ProductDTO productDTO = new ProductDTO();

        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        System.out.println("session---------3-"+productId);
        productDTO = (ProductDTO) session.get(ProductDTO.class, (int) productId);
        if(productDTO!=null){
            System.out.println("session---------4-"+productDTO.getProductId());
            System.out.println("session---------5-"+productDTO.getProductName());
            System.out.println("session---------6-"+productDTO.getProductPrice());
        }else{
            System.out.println("session---------7-");
        }

        session.close();
        return productDTO;
    }
}
```